# Why are some signal attributes implicit signals while others are not?

Tags: vhdl

In VHDL some signal attributes (eg 'TRANSACTION) are *implicit signals*. Others (eg 'EVENT) are not. Why is this?

Comment: Static signal names (signal attributes with static signal name prefixes, 8.1) can be evaluated in condition clauses or used in sensitivity lists of wait statements (10.2). The other three (S'DELAYED(T), S'STABLE(T), and S'QUIET(T)) can be used in evaluating model timing. S'TRANSACTION can be used to signal activity (as opposed to events resulting from value change). Predefined signal attributes that are not signals are functions  used to examine model signal characteristics.

Comment: @user1155120 So, it would seem that whether an attribute is a signal or function or constant or whatever depends on which is the most **useful**. It is certainly useful to write things like `wait on S'TRANSACTION;`. Of course, it is also useful to write `wait on S;`; and because `wait on` already waits for _events_ , it isn't useful for `'EVENT` to be a signal (for example).

Comment: There's also another distinction with implicit signals. They can't be accessed in a subprogram body because subprogram calls are dynamically elaborated and implemented by value copy. There's no hat to hang a pointer (access) to the explicit ancestor on. This tells us the predefined signal attributes returning signals are basic operations and not functions. They return the signal values by kernel process 'system magic' and not by functions that the language user could replicate.

Answer (score 2):

The returned VHDL object, its type and value is not restricted by the language. Wheras user-defined attributes are restricted to be constant values.

> **6.7 Attribute declarations**
>   An attribute is a value, function, type, range, signal, or constant that may be associated with one or more named entities in a description. There are two categories of attributes: predefined attributes and user-defined attributes. Predefined attributes provide information about named entities in a description. Clause 16 contains the definition of all predefined attributes. Predefined attributes that are signals shall not be updated.
>
> User-defined attributes are **constants** of arbitrary type. Such attributes are defined by an attribute declaration.
>
> § 6.7 on p. 92, IEEE Standard VHDL Language Reference Manual, IEEE Standard 1076-2008

So built-in attributes can map to almost everything. In case of `'transaction` the return object is a `signal` of type `bit`.

The attribute or *tick* syntax is a nice compact thing in the VHDL language. It's used for several purposes.

Comment: You don't refer to *implicit signals*, mentioned in the question. Is this incorrect terminology in the question, or is there more to this?

Comment: @scary_jeff The OP already knows that there are *implicit* signals, so I didn't add a full list of them: `transaction`, `delayed`, `stable`, `quiet`.

Comment: I was wondering why the different transactions were signals or constants or whatever. It seems from @user1155120 's comment above, that whichever they are perhaps depends on which is the most **useful** (in other words, the designers of the language chose the most useful one).

Comment: But why is `quiet` more useful as a signal? I had assumed that all the attributes that return true or false were equivalent to functions with a boolean return value. Perhaps my question is outside the scope of this SO question altogether.

Comment: @scary_jeff I think your question is entirely in scope. If the designers of the language thought it would be useful to have `'QUIET` as a signal (and `'STABLE`), I wonder why. Perhaps it could be useful to `wait on S'STABLE` and hence `'QUIET` is a signal for consistency?